# How to convert Array formula to equivalent regular formula in excel?

Tags: excel

I need to convert the below array formula to equivalent regular formula.

**{=SUM(IF(ROUND(A1:A5,0)>0,1,0))}**

How to replace this array formula to regular formula for same behaviour

Comment: Fundementally an array formula is a regular formula which is calculated over many cells at once. In order to 'convert it' to a regular formula, you will need to either (a) perform that formula on each individual cell and then combine it somehow on another cell; or (b) change the logic of your formula to something that Excel can calculate all at once. How to do this in any given case depends on precisely what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to convert it to regular formula, then you have to first use `=Round()` formula on `A1:A5` cells then you have to use `Countif()` formula.

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B6,">0")
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is good because it really shows two things as I mention in my comment above: first, the initial rounding must be done on each individual cell [if you aren't using an array formula]. Second, it shows, that Excel has a formula which works on many cells at once - COUNTIF. From a logic perspective, COUNTIF is basically the same as an Array Formula using an If statement, but from an operation perspective, Excel allows you to use it without the special CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to do this for some VBA manipulation? Or is it just a cell formula.

If its the manual changing of an array formula cells...

1. Select the whole data range that the formula is defined. An easy way to do this is select any cell in the array formula, and Press CTRL + G, select Special Cells, then Current Array.
2. With the whole array selected press F2 to edit the formula, then press CTRL and ENTER. This will remove the array constraints and you can change the formula accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula converting array formula into normal ones, which is SUMPRODUCT. However, the final result should be a number, not a text.

In the above mentioned case, I would use =SUMPRODUCT(--(round(a1:a5,0)>0)